# React native - Append to state object using setState

Tags: react-native, react-state-management, react-state

my state object looks like this:

```
activeUsers: {
    country: {userID:{userProfileObject}}
}
```

and I am trying to update state like this

```
this.setState(
    {
        activeUsers: {
            ...this.state.activeUsers,
            country: {userID: userProfileObject},
        },
    }
)
```

but it doesnt seem to work.....anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Maybe you can be a bit more specific. What sort of problems are you running into? Also, from the description of your state it's not clear why you added `...this.state.activeUsers`

Comment: Look at your code, I saw that you update data with the same key `country`. You could provide the context and more info about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put state directly, instead of it you need to have key-value pair for resu

```
 this.setState(
    {
        activeUsers: {newData: {...this.state.activeUsers}, country: {userID: "12345"}},
    })
```

Here **newData** is new key where i put state value, you can make it anyway you want.

You can do it like this:

```
this.setState(
    {
        activeUsers: {country1: {...this.state.activeUsers.country}, country: {userID: "12345"}},
    }
)
```

Please let me know, if it worked for you. Thanks